# Slightly smaller sized of div element (css computed size is 0.085 smaller)

Tags: html, css

I have got a div with fixed height/width to 24px and background picture
but 0.1 pixel is cropped by the browser...

```css
div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(svg);
}
```

When I see at the computed styles - the height is 23.9915px (attached the picture)

Why it happens? is it some king of aliasing/smoothing? Can anyone explain how to handle such cases?

[image: cropped picture]
[image: Slightly smaller div width/height]

Comment: and please share your code for more clearification

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found out, that the page has been zoomed 110%

After returning to 100% 24px became 24px